# Is their any way to store nested document in Solr?

Tags: json, solr, nested

I am a beginner to Solr. I am trying to store nested document/JSON into the Solr document.

```
{
        "source_ln":"en",
        "source_text":"I joined a gym",
        "target_ln":"hi",
        "target_text":"मैंने एक जिम ज्वाइन किया",
        "organizations":["2e540ba1-fbe3-4aba-b77a-d78755f917b2"],
        "tags": {
           "food": 2, 
           "travel": 2
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Solr will be able to do that. Thanks to the  Block Join Query Parsers.

There are few things to take care before you try to do that.

- The schema must include an indexed/non-stored field `root`
- You must include a field that identifies the parent document as a parent.
- A special `childDocuments` key need to indicate the nested documents in JSON

Read more on [Solr Nested documents](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-NestedChildDocuments)

example

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Solr adds block join support",
    "content_type": "parentDocument",
    "_childDocuments_": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "comments": "SolrCloud supports it too!"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "title": "New Lucene and Solr release is out",
    "content_type": "parentDocument",
    "_childDocuments_": [
      {
        "id": "4",
        "comments": "Lots of new features"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is exactly I was looking for.